# I want to use Angular Signals, do I have to turn of zone.js?

Tags: angular, signals, angular-signals

With Angular 16 came Signals as Developer Preview.

When i want to use Signals, do i have to turn of zone.js. And if you so, is Signals taking place the job from zone.js automaticcly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signal are still hooked on the `NgZone` for change detection, so you'll still need `zone.js` if you want automatic CD.

If you want to try to go zoneless, you can use this non-public provider:

```
boostrapApplication(AppComponent, {providers: [{provide: NgZone, useClass: ɵNoopNgZone}]})
```

But, again, this will disable automatic change detection.

Comment: To add to this ... the *ultimate* goal of signals is to allow for removal of zone.js. But those features have not yet been implemented. So as mentioned, zone.js is still required.